# Kotlin multiplication return wrong result

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi guys i have a problem for multiplication calculation in kotlin. Below I attach the code and the expected result is **69103085.89**

this happen even I delete `.toBigDecimal()` function. How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Hi, please can you replace your screenshot with the actual code ([explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4161471)).

Comment: `8875.87 * 778.55 = 6910308.5885` [Google calculator](https://www.google.com/search?q=8875.87+*+778.55) [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=decimal+%5C%2840%298875.87+*+778.55%5C%2841%29+). Why do you expect `69103085.89`?

Comment: @aSemy ummm i just realize, there is difference with the result when i check to some of different calculator. this confusing

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you are declaring a double, `8875.87`, and *then* turning it into a BigDecimal. There is no exact double-precision floating point representation for `8875.87` so the rounding has already occurred before you call `toBigDecimal`.

To keep the precision, you need to pass the values to the `BigDecimal` constructor as a string:

```
val a = BigDecimal("8875.87")
val b = BigDecimal("778.55")
println("${a*b}")
```

Comment: I agree the String BigDecimal constructor is best - but in this case, while `8875.87` doesn't have a exact representation (`println(BigDecimal(8875.87))` outputs `8875.870000000000800355337560176849365234375`), `toBigDecimal()` works [because it calls `toString()`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.5.0/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/util/BigDecimals.kt#L127), [and `toString()` will round the double](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)), and so `BigDecimal("8875.87") == 8875.87.toBigDecimal()` returns `true`

Answer (score 0):

For Getting  n decimal digit value. Here n=2.

```
  fun main() {
    val a =8875.87
    val b = 778.55
    val res:Double= (a*b).roundTo(2)

println("${res}") 
}
fun Double.roundTo(n : Int) : Double {
    return "%.${n}f".format(this).toDouble()
}
```